Docker 'RUN' directive and interactive shell behave differently
I have the following Dockerfile as part of a larger docker compose project.
FROM node:slim AS node

# Update package list and install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git python3 make gcc g++ libc6-dev libpng-dev python3-pip \
    libpixman-1-dev libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev pkg-config libtool automake build-essential --no-install-recommends && \
    apt-get clean

# Fix for Python3.12 and node-gyp
RUN python3 -m pip install setuptools --break-system-packages

# Update npm and install global dependencies
RUN npm install -g npm@latest
RUN npm install -g node-gyp

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json file and install dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install

# Copy the application source code
COPY . /app

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 3000

# Set the environment variables
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

# Start the application
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && npm run start"]
# CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

However, this results in the following error:
sudo docker logs 3c41c08f610d
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:

> landon.pw@0.0.1 start
> node ./app.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1724
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1724:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1303:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:218:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1325:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:136:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1546:14)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1698:10) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

The interest thing though, is that if I commit the container with an interactive entrypoint (ie sh), via
docker commit 3c41c08f610d landon/test
docker run -ti --entrypoint=sh landon/test

# pwd
/app
# npm start

> landon.pw@0.0.1 start
> node ./app.js

App listening on port 3000!

it works with no issues. I've tried asking ChatGPT for some help, and most of it revolves around LD library so I added some debugging to make sure environment variables were being set properly and we can see LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib: so looks like it is. If the library truly didn't exist, then surely running npm start through the interactive shell wouldn't work?
Also found a similar issue here, and they recommended to add node_modules to .dockerignore which I tried and the issue still persists. The package-lock.json and node_modules are also included in my .gitignore and I do a fresh pull each time for testing, so it shouldn't be have a conflicting set of modules being copied over to the container during build.
Thanks for any help

You shouldn't normally need to set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  In your setup you're setting it to include system directories that are already in /etc/ld.so.conf.  You're also only installing C shared libraries using the distribution package manager, and they'll be installed in the right place.  Does removing this ENV setting help at all?

docker commit isn't usually encouraged, and it seems like it shouldn't be necessary here.  If you docker-compose run your-service sh, without committing, do you see the same results?

@DavidMaze The ENV was a suggestion from ChatGPT. The issue persisted with and without manually setting the environment variables. Also wasn't aware of docker compose run <service> sh. I ended up just doing a full docker system prune -a, docker volume prune -a, etc. and the issue went away. I'm not sure what exactly was happening.

What is in your Compose file?  Many Node setups seem to like to keep the node_modules tree in an anonymous volume, which will ignore changes in the underlying image, and while this is kind of an obscure problem it's not inconsistent with a problem like that.  In particular, if your Node service has volumes: in the Compose file, you might see if deleting that helps.

I ended up just doing a full docker system prune -a and docker volume prune -a and the issue went away. Not entirely sure what was going on but that worked for me.

It´s probably because the dockerfile user npm run start but when you enter on interactive mode you are using nodejs commmand.
echo 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' on this point, this is the other difference, and the error looks that something are missing. Could you test the CMD command exactly on interactive mode?
